Spring Transactions: Changes not persisted when using @Async methods with @Transactional
This is the flow of my application :
class A {
  @Transactional
  public void foo() {
    // insert rows into a table
    async_job();
    //..
  }
}

class B{
  @Async
  public void async_job() {
    bar();
  }
}

class C{
  @Transactional
  public void bar(){
    // make updates to rows inserted during foo.
  }
}


When running without Async, the code works perfectly. But Adding @Async prevents any inserts appearing in the table.
I have tried

setting propagation type to REQUIRED_NEW for bar method
setting ISOLATION level to SERIALIZABLE in foo method - works, but its inconsistent.

Expectation is that foo() spins up a separate thread which executes bar() and the inserts and updates are persisted to DB after bar completes execution.

@async will start your transaction in a different thread.
That is why you are having issues.
When you call the foo(), it is marked transactional which means it expects all the transactions to be completed withing a single database transaction and single thread.
After this, you call your async_job() which was supposed to join the previous transaction but it won't as you have marked it with @async, here the whole purpose of a single transaction gets eliminated.
Why don't you mark your foo() as @async? This way your entire transaction will run within a separate single thread but in a single database transaction.
Or you can try executing the bar() after a while using TimerTask
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
           // make updates to rows inserted during foo.
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
    
    long delay = 1000L;
    timer.schedule(task, delay);


Since Spring links transactions to the current execution thread, and the Async annotation makes a new thread to be started, there is no propagation of transactions between the caller and the called bean. Please check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-async-annotation with some analysis of possible usage combinations of these two annotations.
